# Вопрос понимающим javascript

Tags: javascript

```
//есть например 3 одинаковых div-а 

<div class = "square">1</div>
<div class = "square">2</div>
<div class = "square">3</div>


//при вызове document.querySelector(".square").style.color = "red" срабатывает только один

//вопрос!, как сделать так чтобы при изменении цвета сработали все 3 div-а
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.querySelectorAll(".square").forEach(el => el.style.color = "red");
```

---

```
document.querySelectorAll(".square").forEach(function(el) { el.style.color = "red"; });
```

Comment: forEach понял (для каждого) а что означает el и еще знак (равно больше) или это стрелка?

Comment: @Мнебезсахара Это стрелка в определении "стрелочной функции".